# Regex pattern to match & extract variables from math/algebraic expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I’m trying to write a regex/method that extracts Variables from an input String that represents “math/algebraic  expression” and a special pattern that looks like this “PROPERTY(AnyOtherAplhaNumeric)” which can also be a variable.

**My definition of a variable:**

1)  Can contain alphanumeric values only

2)  Must be at least 1 char or more

3)  Cannot start with a digit , must start with [A-Za-z]

4)  A variable for example “X”, can be surrounded by this string “PROPERTY(X)”,  therefore the variable becomes “PROPERTY(X)”

**My current Method & Regex (works only in some cases):**

```
public Set<String> extractUniqueVarsFromExpression(String expression) {
        Set<String> varsSet = null;
        Pattern p = null;
        Matcher m = null;
        System.out.println(expression);
        if (expression != null) {
            varsSet = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<String>();
            //"[A-Za-zPROPERTY(?)_][A-Za-z0-9PROPERTY(?)_]*||[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*"
            //"[[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*"
            p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zPROPERTY(?)_][A-Za-z0-9PROPERTY(?)_]*||[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*",
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            m = p.matcher(expression);
            while (m.find()) {

                    String group = m.group().trim();
                //do not add duplicates     

                         if (!varsSet.contains(group)) 
                         {
                    varsSet.add(group);

                    System.out.println(" Variable : " + group);
                         }//end if not duplicate 

            }// end while

        }
        System.out.println();
        return varsSet;
    }
```

**Examples/Cases:**

**Ex #1:**

Input: [(ibdweight / ibdheight) * ibdheight] * 703

Output:

Variable : PROPERTY(ibdweight)

Variable : PROPERTY(ibdheight)

**Ex #2:**

Input: [ibdweight / ibdheight * ibdheight] * 703

Output:

Variable : ibdweight

Variable : ibdheight

**Ex #3:**

Input: [PROPERTY(ibdweight) / [PROPERTY(ibdheight) * PROPERTY(ibdheight)] * 703

Output:

Variable : PROPERTY(ibdweight)

Variable : PROPERTY(ibdheight)

**Ex #:4**

**These are the cases that don’t work (examples 4 to 6):**

**The problem is the parenthesis are being picked up as variables:**

Input: ( Mass * ( Acceleration + whatever ))

Output:

Variable : (

Variable : Mass

Variable : Acceleration

Variable : whatever

Variable : ))

**Ex #:5**

**The problem is the parenthesis are being picked up as variables:**

Input: ( Base * Height ) / 2

Output:

Variable : (

Variable : Base

Variable : Height

Variable : )

**Ex #:6**

**The problem is the parenthesis are being picked up as variables OR attached to a variable:**

Input: [((( var * var2 ) var3 ) + ( var1 / var4 ) var5) / var6 ]

Output:

Variable : (((

Variable : var

Variable : var2

Variable : )

Variable : var3

Variable : (

Variable : var1

Variable : var4

Variable : var5)

Variable : var6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is that you have the both the parentheses and the word "PROPERTY" *inside* of the brackets.  Brackets are for specifying a set of characters, not strings, any member of which will match.

A simple (although probably not optimal) variation that should work for you is:
`(PROPERTY\([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\))|([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)`

A slightly better version would be:
`(PROPERTY\([A-Za-z]\w*\))|([A-Za-z]\w*)`

Comment: i tried your regex and so far its working, Thanks, by the why whats a really good regex tutorial , thats rigorous but short andto the point specially for dealing with complex cases

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a good one.  I learned a long time ago when I learned Perl.  My (very old) Perl book had lots of examples, but sadly I no longer have it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is the way that you are thinking about the regex.

As an example:

```
    [A-Za-zPROPERTY(?)_]
```

This is essentially a "character class"  which is not behaving the way that you are expecting.  It will match ANY single character in the input string that matches ANY of the characters in the class.  It does not treat PROPERTY as a single entity, but rather as separate uppercase letters (which are already included with the A-Z, anyway. Also, having (?) in your character class is matching "(", which I am sure is not what you want.